# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in QUnit test

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am trying to test simple example with qUnit. it shows me error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in test.js file.

I am using express server in javascript but not using jQuery.

qunit.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.18.0.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.18.0.js"></script>
  <script src="test/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test/test.js

```
QUnit.test( "hello test", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});
```

Comment: Please provide some code for us to examine so we can help determine the cause of your error.

Comment: Can you please post your example, including the portion of tested code? Questions need a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

wrap the ***Qunit.test*** inside a ***Qunit.module***

```
QUnit.module('qunit testing', function () {
    QUnit.test( "hello test", function( assert ) {
        assert.ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
    });
});
```